# ORDER BY breaking mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, join, sql-order-by, inner-join

Someone on here helped put together this extremely useful query!

```
SELECT * FROM results r 
INNER JOIN categories c on r.id = c.result_id 
WHERE c.name in ('$purpose', '$prop_type', '$loan_type')
GROUP BY r.id
HAVING COUNT(c.c_id) = 3
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

Which is working great! However, when I try to order the results by using

```
SELECT * FROM results r 
INNER JOIN categories c on r.id = c.result_id 
WHERE c.name in ('$purpose', '$prop_type', '$loan_type')
ORDER BY r.usefulness DESC
GROUP BY r.id
HAVING COUNT(c.c_id) = 3
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

I get a syntax error. Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The order by should be your last criteria.

Comment: Thanks everyone. knew it would be something simple!

Comment: (unrelated to the problem): You probably only need `SELECT r.*`. Not `SELECT *`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is an order for the parts of the query, and `ORDER BY` should be in the end (before the `LIMIT` and the `OFFSET`... try this:

```
SELECT * FROM results r 
INNER JOIN categories c on r.id = c.result_id 
WHERE c.name in ('$purpose', '$prop_type', '$loan_type')
GROUP BY r.id
HAVING COUNT(c.c_id) = 3
ORDER BY usefulness DESC
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

also make sure that you have spaces in the end of any row...

notice that in mysql that is a shortened version for `LIMIT x OFFSET y` - you can just write `LIMIT y,x`

Comment: Why have spaces in the end of the lines?

Comment: Makes sense, but the spaces at the end of the lines is a bit strange.

Comment: it depends how you run the query, if (for example) the query is in a multiline string (in PHP - again for example) than when you call the sql server it removes the line breaks, and if you don't have spaces in the end of the line - your lines connects, and that causing errors in the better case, or unwanted behavior in the worst case...

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY` has to come after the `HAVING`.